# Custom paging using GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, pagination

I have followed [Custom Pagination](https://web.archive.org/web/20210510021915/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031506-1.aspx) article to implement the custom pagination using GridView.
I have also done custom pagination using the DataGrid but i am still confused on following things.

1. DataGrid which is there in the ASP.NET 1.1 having VirtualItemCount which is set to render the pagination interface [1 2 3 4 5 ... something like this]
2. GridView does not have the above mentioned property then how to generate the pagination UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paging in the GridView isn't nearly as powerful as I'd like, especially when it comes to templating. But there are a few options that work well enough. Try adding this to your grid view.

```
<PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" />
```

You can also use: NextPrevious, NumericFirstLast, and Numeric

Comment: No I don't think this is something that i am really looking for. i want to do the Custom Paging instead of saying select * i would like to get the slice of data back only not entire data. Now with this how can i implement the pagination interface is what my question.

Comment: Oh, I gotcha now. I did something like this a while back, maybe I can dig it up. Hopefully this could help for now: http://beta.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/GridViewNeatPaging.aspx?msg=2476422